# Equivalent of Informix GLOBAL modifier in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, informix

I need to find equivalent of Informix GLOBAL modifier in Postgresql.
From Informix guide:
The GLOBAL keyword indicates that the variables that follow have a scope of reference that includes all SPL routines that run in a given DB-Access or SQL administration API session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postgres [set session "configuration parameters"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set.html) have session scope:

> SET only affects the value used by the current session.

Example usage:

```
set session "myvars.var1" = '3.1415';
...
select current_setting('myvars.var1');
```